# Why does this url raise BadStatusLine with httplib2 and urllib2?

Tags: python, urllib2, httplib2

Using httplib2 and urllib2, I'm trying to fetch pages from this url, but all of them didn't work out and ended up with this exception.

```
content = conn.request(uri="http://www.zdnet.co.kr/news/news_print.asp?artice_id=20110727092902")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1129, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 901, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 871, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1027, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
```

HTTP header was like this

```
http://www.zdnet.co.kr/news/news_print.asp?artice_id=20110727092902

GET /news/news_print.asp?artice_id=20110727092902 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.zdnet.co.kr
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ko-kr,ko;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: RMID=7d83495d4f336fe0; __utma=37206251.1552605885.1328771258.1328771258.1329070845.2; __utmz=37206251.1328771258.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ASPSESSIONIDCSQCQTDD=BCLEHPPDEPHEBJDLCFNDMKDN; __utmc=37206251; ASPSESSIONIDSSQCQQCB=MJPLMOJAFPDFCLONCANBIKHN; _EXEN=2
X-FireLogger: 1.2

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2012 18:02:56 GMT
Content-Length: 19158
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8; Charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSQSDQRDB=NGAIFHKAGDIOGEMANAOLLKKF; path=/
Cache-Control: private
```

Any clue?

Comment: Please post your connect statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener()

headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1',
}

opener.addheaders = headers.items()
response = opener.open("http://www.zdnet.co.kr/news/news_print.asp?artice_id=20110727092902")

print response.headers
print response.read()
```

The website discards all requests that occur without a `User-Agent` string.

Answer (score 4):

For all the people that end up here with a similar problem after installing httplib2 0.8:

Version 0.8 has a regression with connection handling in relation with HTTP keep-alive. See the bug report: https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/issues/detail?id=250

There is a fix for this issue, but it has not been released so far. Until then just use httplib2 0.7.7.

Answer (score 2):

In my code,when i use

```
    from urllib2 import urlopen  
    content = urlopen(page).read()
```

the exception appears. However, when i use

```
    import urllib  
    content = urllib.urlopen(page).read()
```

everything is ok. 
Maybe it will help u.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks. But it would be nice to know why urllib2 doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Look like this webpage doesn't allow your user agent. You can change it like this:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
>>> headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
>>> r = urllib2.Request('http://www.zdnet.co.kr/news/news_print.asp?artice_id=20110727092902', headers=headers)
>>> fd = urllib2.urlopen(r)
>>> print fd[20:]
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLI'
```