# What is the proper user-agent to use for a server?

Tags: http, request, user-agent

For [Filepicker.io](https://www.filepicker.io) we built "grab from url", but certain sites aren't happy with not passing a User-Agent header. I could just use a stock browser user agent as suggested in some other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265616/why-does-this-url-raise-badstatusline-with-httplib2-and-urllib2), but as a good web citizen I wanted to know if there isa more appropriate user-agent to set for a server requesting another server's data?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the language you wrote your server in. For example, Python's urllib sets a default value to `User-agent: Python-urllib/2.1`, but you can just as easily set it to something like `User-agent: filepicker.io/<your-version-here>` or something more language specific if you'd like.