# Downloading torrent file using urllib2

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, httplib, torrent

I am trying to download torrent files using urllib2, but it gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "download_torrent.py", line 11, in <module>
  torr_file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
File "C:\Users\Aly Akhtar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Users\Aly Akhtar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Users\Aly Akhtar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
  '_open', req)
File "C:\Users\Aly Akhtar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Aly Akhtar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
  context=self._context)
File "C:\Users\Aly Akhtar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1200, in do_open
  r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
File "C:\Users\Aly Akhtar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 1132, in getresponse
  response.begin()
File "C:\Users\Aly Akhtar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 453, in begin
  version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "C:\Users\Aly Akhtar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\httplib.py", line 417, in _read_status
  raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

Following is the code that I am trying:

```
url = 'https://torcache.net/torrent/7E74F1E4AEDC08A2D63BE1EDF612AC0BF17ECBBD.torrent?title=[kat.cr]batman.v.superman.dawn.of.justice.2016.720p.hdtc.1.2gb.shaanig'
torr_file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
with open("mytorrent.torrent", "w") as f:
    f.write(torr_file.read())
```

I have gone through a few similar questions, but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website you're trying to download from seems to discard requests without a `User-Agent` string in the header. I found a solution to your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265980/1577207.

Adding a `User-Agent` header solves it for me:

```
import urllib2
url = 'https://torcache.net/torrent/7E74F1E4AEDC08A2D63BE1EDF612AC0BF17ECBBD.torrent?title=[kat.cr]batman.v.superman.dawn.of.justice.2016.720p.hdtc.1.2gb.shaanig'

opener = urllib2.build_opener()

headers = {
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1',
}

opener.addheaders = headers.items()
torr_file = opener.open(url)
with open("mytorrent.torrent", "w") as f:
    f.write(torr_file.read())
```

Comment: well it does solve my above stated problem,Thanks. But now the torrent file when opened using a client gives an error: torrent is not valid bencoding

Comment: @AlyAkhtar You can try adding the `'b'` option to `open()`, like this: `open(file, 'wb')` for binary file writing.